# Excel 2013 - Add efforts (days and hours) to calculate task end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In excel 2013, for a small project, I am trying to compute the end date & time of a task, based on the start date & time and efforts.

**Assumptions:**

- Work Start Time: 07:00 AM
- Work End Time  : 15:00
- Work Hours     : 8
- Working Days   : Sun - Thu

For example, if Start Date = 29-Dec-16 07:00

1. Efforts (Days) = 0.5, End Date: Expected is 29-Dec-16 11:00
2. Efforts (Days) = 1.0, End Date: Expected is 29-Dec-16 15:00
3. Efforts (Days) = 1.5, End Date: Expected is 30-Dec-16 11:00
4. Efforts (Days) = 2.5, End Date: Expected is 31-Dec-16 11:00

I'm using the `WorkDay.Intl` function, using weekdays = 7, to compute the end date.

Additionally, am also trying to populate the start date of the next row based on the end date of the previous row. For eg: If the end date of the previous row is 30-Dec-16 11:00, start date of the next row should be same as end date of the previous row. However, if the end date is 30-Dec-16 15:00, then start date should be 31-Dec-16 07:00.

Can somebody please help?

Thanks in anticipation.

Regards
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find a way of dealing with the three edge cases

(1) Where the previous end time is 15:00

(2) Where the new end time falls exactly on 15:00, e.g. starting at 11:00 and working for four hours (effort=0.5)

(3) Where the previous end time plus any fraction part of the effort overflows into the next day, e.g. starting at 11:00 and working for 6 hours (effort=0.75) so finishing at 9:00 the next day.

I found it easier to use a helper column to store the fractional days for cases (2) and (3).

So starting with 28/12/2016 15:00 in D2 and the effort in B3, put the following in A3, C3 and D3:

```
=IF(MOD(D2,1)=15/24,WORKDAY.INTL(D2,1,7)+7/24,D2)

=MOD(A3-7/24,1)*3+MOD(B3,1)

=IF(ROUND(MOD(C3,1),6)=0,WORKDAY.INTL(A3,INT(B3)+C3-1,7)+15/24,WORKDAY.INTL(A3,INT(B3)+C3,7)+MOD(C3,1)/3+7/24)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom Sharpe. Solution by @Mike also worked with addition of workday.intl function. Both worked perfectly well. I integrated this into my main formula, which computes the end date based on few more parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got based on your description:

A1:A3 : Start, Effort, End
A2 = The first start date (in this case 12/29/2016 07:00 AM)
In A3 copied down:

```
=IF(C2<>"No Effort",IF(C2<>"",C2,""),"")
```

In C2 copied down:

```
=IF(A2<>"",IF(B2<>"",IF(MOD(B2,1)=0,A2+INT(B2),A2+INT(B2)+(MOD(B2,1)*8)/24),"No Effort"),"")
```

Then in B2 and down you put what ever decimal of Effort you need and the end of the previous day will be the start of each following day. And the end of each day will be the days and hours added from the Effort.

[image]

[image]